# Sharepoint Central Administration 3.0 (2007) - HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007

I've just installed Sharepoint 2007 Server and starting the Central Administration I first got a HTTP 503. This was due to the ApplicationPool was stopped. Changing the pool credentials I got it to start.

Now the problem is that I get HTTP Error 500.19.

I've checked that my user has access rights to the web.config file, and I've even added 'Everyone' with read access to that file.

Where to go next??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find how to resolve this issue, but did a uninstall/reinstall of Sharepoint 2007. The problem did not occur after the reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

The IIS website is run by either `USERS` or `IIS_IUSRS`.

Try to do following:

1. Open the Central Administration in IIS.
2. Right click on it & click Explorer.
3. Right click on the folder pointed by the web.
4. Go to security tab, add `IIS_IUSRS` or `USERS` group with Read permission.

I hope this might help you...!

Comment: It did not help, but I uninstalled and re-installed Sharepoint 2007. Strangely enough, the issue was gone..

Comment: That's nice but above given answer was one of the solution for the central admin permission issues